# How to I delete a song from ITunes and re-download

Tags: iphone, itunes

all...I'm having trouble with a song I downloaded from iTunes.  I fixed it once before, but I can't remember what I did.

I have a song that I bought and it only partially downloaded (only the first 40 seconds play).  I paid for the song, so I can download it again to my iPhone and computer, but not until I figure out how to delete the one that only partially plays.  Otherwise, I don't get the option to download, only to "play".  Anyone know how I can delete the incomplete song from my iPhone so I can download it from scratch again?

I'm able to delete it from my computer, but when I synch, the stupid partial song gets added back.

Thanks!
Michele

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to right click on the song in iTunes and "Delete" - it will then ask you if you want to delete the song from your computer as well, which you will allow. Then sync your device, which will remove the song that is on it (or just open up the music on your device and delete that individual song) - redownload the song, and put it back on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a common bug with iTunes downloads. You can read about it here: http://www.mcelhearn.com/2012/07/30/whats-going-on-with-truncated-itunes-downloads/

At the bottom of that blog post, it has a link to an app that can search your whole library for these truncated tracks, and puts them all in a playlist so you can delete and re-download them. http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=findtruncatedtracks