# I can't re-download a song with iTunes on my PC or iPhone

Tags: itunes

I bought an album yesterday from iTunes on my PC, downloaded it, and synced it with my iPhone.  When I later tried to play the songs on the phone, I noticed that they wouldn't play at all.  I also noticed that they wouldn't play on the PC.  So, I tried to follow the suggestion in this [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73392/how-to-i-delete-a-song-from-itunes-and-re-download) and deleted the songs, thinking I could just re-download them.  I can't seem to actually re-download these.

1. I locate the album in the iTunes store from iTunes on my PC.
2. I click "buy" for the album.
3. I see a pop-up box from iTunes telling me I have already purchased this item and can redownload it from my Purchases.
4. I click the "Purchased" button on the pop-up dialog.
5. iTunes takes me to "Purchased" screen, but I do not see the artist or any of the songs from that artist in my purchased music list.

Also, when I try to download it from iTunes directly from my iPhone, the album shows up with a "purchased" box next to it already and is unclickable.

I am using iTunes 11 on my PC and have iOS 6.0.1 on the iPhone.

How can I get this music?

Comment: I don’t know how to solve this, but if you are not able to solve it by following future answers, contact Apple Support and they will refund you. Buy the album again.

Comment: Please read this [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1408?viewlocale=en_US) by Apple. If that doesn't help, you should contact them through their [Express Lane Support](https://expresslane.apple.com).

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem and I tried the same solution you did: deleted the file and could not redownload. It just said "Purchased" and there was no option to redownload. It turns out that I must have selected to "hide" the purchase. I fixed this by going to my account settings in itunes and clicking "view hidden purchases". Low and behold, my missing file was there. I clicked the "unhide" button and was able to download it again from the itunes store.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

You have to go back to iTunes and instead of going to the album, go to the songs it previews right below it. The missing songs will have the "buy $???" Option. You need to select that option, and once you do it will say you have already purchased it and will ask if you want to download again for free. Say yes and your missing song(s) will download. 
Repeat step for all other missing songs individually.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to obtain "PURCHASED" tracks on a new release. This doesn't involve deleting or hiding purchases. It may involve paying for tracks you obtained on a prior release, but that's expected as it's a new release even if the track is the same.

1. "Complete the album" as normal; this downloads any tracks it detects as non-purchased, but does not deliver "PURCHASED" tracks.
2. Find a $0.99 button (or other price) [instead of PURCHASED] for the remaining tracks. I found these in two areas: (A) on the mobile store: anywhere the tracks are displayed outside of the album view, such as in the Songs subcategory in a search for the artist; (B) in the desktop app, in the downloaded album in your library: select to show all tracks, including non-downloaded. For the tracks I couldn't find in A, I used B.
3. Obtain the tracks using the $0.99 button (or other price). In some cases, it may say you purchased this track previously so you can download it for free. In other cases, it may be a new purchase. (I'm not sure whether this directly relates to ISRCs as in my case all ISRCs matched previous releases.) In my case, most tracks were new purchases and the total cost worked out to the same as buying the entire album normally had I been able to.

You should now have access to all tracks specifically from that album instead of just prior releases (if you used method B above for any tracks, and you want them on another device like your iPhone, you can now download them on that device, e.g. at iTunes Store > More > Purchased > Music > [Artist]).